# Determining noise performance of clipper circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, bjt, voltage-clipping

In some audio circuits (e.g. instrument amplifiers and guitar effects), I've seen something similar to the following op-amp circuit with back-to-back V<sub>BE</sub> multipliers in the feedback loop to provide gain while limiting the output signal.

The idea is that the user will start to hear relatively gentle clipping, and ease off on the upstream gain before driving the output to the rails.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB9y1d.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The transfer function looks like this:
[image]

I'm wondering about the noise performance of this circuit, and whether the choice of transistors makes much difference in that regard.

The resistor values in the simulation are not based on any particular "real life" instance of this circuit, but just to illustrate the likely orders of magnitude.  I selected the multiplier ratio so that the output swing might stay within the limits of an op-amp powered by a 9V battery.

I have used the custom "Ideal-ish" op-amp because CircuitLab doesn't have a properly ideal component.  I wanted to focus on the noise component of the  discrete components rather than get into a discussion about op-amp types.  However (see my concluding parenthetical remark) if most real-life op-amps are going to produce considerably more noise, then please point that out.

In the "important" part of the signal swing (close to ground, far from rails), we have very little current flowing in the transistors (current noise from the transistors is lowest when I<sub>c</sub> is low) and most of the current through the feedback loop flowing in the resistors.

It seems like the noise introduced by the transistors should be negligible compared to the noise from the resistors, but I'm not sure how to approach it quantitatively.  (Or whether the orders of magnitude involved will tell us not to bother looking at it quantitatively.)

Comment: My bet is that a real op amp will be the biggest culprit so, saying it is ideal (ish) might be missing the point. Try simulating it.

Comment: It might make a big difference trying to find a low rbb BJT in certain cases. But in this case your source impedances to the BJTs are around 200 Ohms and 400 Ohms, thereabouts. So the rbb won't factor much in the noise question on this point. Common BJTs have rbb around 20-40 Ohms, more or less.

Comment: What dynamic range are you expecting? Since clipping won't start until about 5V p-p and noise will be in the sub-microvolt level is it relevant?

Comment: I think you can ignore any noise the transistors may contribute because the transistors are completely off in the “important” part (Input<0.5Vpk), and after that the intentional distortion introduced by the transistors will dominate any THD+N measurement. The output noise will be the opamp’s voltage noise times the noise gain of 6.3 and swamp any noise contributed by your small resistors unless you buy a really nice opamp, but why would you bother in what is essentially a distortion circuit?

Comment: @KevinWhite I think the whole point of the circuit is that it will, in fact act a lot like an arctan curve and the output will flatten out at the extremes. In this circuit, the output flat sections start when the input exceeds on the negative end -600 mV and when it exceeds +600 mV on the positive end. In between, before it mushes out, it's pretty linear in response. If the input never exceeds these, it's kind of pointless complexity. If the input does exceed these, then the output is self-limited to not exceed about +/- 3.5 V.

Comment: @KevinWhite the clipping voltage and the noise are separate issues.  Even when there's no input signal, the noise will be amplified by subsequent signal path.

Comment: @jonk The input generally won't reach the point of clipping the output, but when it occasionally does, it avoids the less predictable clipping or inversion that could occur from driving the output to the rails.  FWIW, I made some updates to the question.

Comment: @Theodore Yes, that's the transfer I was imagining in my head. Adding it will help others. Your noise question included a question about the BJTs, themselves. I don't think their noise will dominate though I do admit that the BJT collector currents have quite a dynamic range in that circuit. The noise sources are many (every PN junction generates shot noise, everything else (almost) generates kT/C or Johnson noise (same thing, either way.) An analysis for S/N over the linear range would take me time. Perhaps not others. Shot noise leads to very bad S/N at low currents, though. It was my bane.

Comment: @Theodore - The noise and clipping are related by the dynamic range you expect. As shown the noise from the resistors will be about 30nV/sqrt(Hz) integrating to about 3 microvolt over the audio range the opamp and input resistor will add more. If your following stages are expected to tolerate the 5v p-p output then they must not overload at that point. However the 3uV noise is over 100dB down from clipping level. You need at least that dynamic range in the following stages. Do you have that?

Comment: @Jonk - I'm not sure what point you are making. I know how it is supposed to work. I was asking what the expectations are for the required dynamic range. My other comment includes further discussion.

Comment: @KevinWhite Then it is entirely my own misunderstanding of your writing goal. That's my problem, not yours. My apologies for bothering you about it.

Comment: You’ve increased your resistors by a factor of ten since your original post. Now R1 is your biggest noise source and everything else is relatively insignificant. R1’s noise is amplified by 4.7 whereas the feedback resistors (47K) noise is not amplified, so it’s R1 that dominates. At 10K, R1’s noise exceeds that of even a crappy opamp.

Comment: @td127 Yes, I took a look at schematics from some commercial products using a similar configuration (although not the same application exactly).  If I make use of this circuit, the value will likely 1k<R1<10k.

Comment: @KevinWhite The absolute highest dynamic range I'd hope for would be the capabilities of a typical "pro-sumer" audio A/D with 24 bit resolution, so signal is about 146 dB above quantization noise.  I don't expect other parts of the signal path would get near there.  The real concern is that with the upstream gain set to keep the signal from clipping here, the "idle" noise of this circuit will be amplified to an objectionable level downstream.  It's music electronics, so you can practically guarantee it will be used *not* as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ltspice can simulate the noise contributions.

But from looking at the schematic a few things become apparent:

- the BJT are off at low signal level, so the noise of the feedback block is dominated by the three feedback resistors.
- at high signal level, the feedback impedance drops (hence rolling back gain), so that means that noise drops too. and anyway the signal will be loud.
- different transistors will slightly change the clipping threshold and even more slightly the THD content when clipping, but not the noise.
- in all of these cases the largest noise contribution will be from the input resistor, as it will be multiplied by the circuit gain..The same applies to the opamp input voltage and current noise, so if these sources are more than the thermal noise of the input resistor, the opamp itself will indeed be the dominant noise source.

Comment: I think you're correct that the feedback resistor noise will dominate the BJT noise, but the input resistor noise is amplified by the gain -(R2+R3+R4)/R1, so @td127's comment above is correct that R1 is the most important noise source.

Comment: @Theodore yes correct.. My reasoning applies only to the noise sources in the feedback block. Added a bullet